# Two textareas showing up in comments.php

Tags: comments

I have the following code to display comments, but there are two text areas showing up, not just one.

Here is my code

```
<?php $comment_args = array( 'title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:',

        $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' ),

        'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

            'author' => '<div class="grid-1-3">' . '<input id="author" placeholder="Name (required)" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></div>',   

            'email'  => '<div class="grid-1-3">' . '<input id="email" placeholder="E-mail (required)" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.'</div>',

            'url'    => '<div class="grid-1-3">' . '<input id="url" placeholder="Website (optional)" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></div>',

            'comment_field' => '<p>' . '<textarea id="comment" placeholder="Your comment here. Be cool." name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' . '</p>',

            'comment_notes_after' => '',


        ))); // line 73


    comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

Any suggestions to what the problem might be?

Comment: You are missing two closing brackets `)`

Comment: You should rephrase your question to be more specific to why you have two text areas as to a syntax error, and post your last update as an answer and also accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why the two textareas were showing up:

The `comment_field` is not supposed to be in the `'fields'` array because it is a distinct parameter for the `comment_form()` function. It should be:

```
'url'    => '<div class="grid-1-3">' . '<input id="url" placeholder="Website (optional)" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></div>',

            )),

            'comment_field' => '<div class="comment-con">' . '<textarea id="comment" placeholder="Your comment here. Be cool." name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' . '</div>',

            'comment_notes_after' => '',

        ); // line 73
```